# Parsing JSON with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am unable to parse JSOn with jquery's get JSON function. Please help. Here is the html code:

```
 function getList()
{
$.getJSON("http://localhost/webservice/list.php", function(data){
    for (var i=0, len=data.length; i < len; i++) 
     {
        alert(data[i]);
    }

});
```

And here is the list.php file which is set to header('Content-type: application/json')

```
{
"promos":[
{"promo":{"id":"1","name":"MADINAT JUMEIRAH AL QASR","image":"","stars":"","highlights":""}},
{"promo":{"id":"2","name":"MADINAT JUMEIRAH DAR AL MASYAF","image":"","stars":"","highlights":""}},
{"promo":{"id":"3","name":"ATLANTIS THE PALM","image":"","stars":"","highlights":""}},
{"promo":{"id":"4","name":"JUMEIRAH ZABEEL SARAY 5*","image":"","stars":"","highlights":""}},
{"promo":{"id":"5","name":"HABTOOR GRAND BEACH RESORT & SPA","image":"","stars":"","highlights":""}},
{"promo":{"id":"6","name":"HILTON DUBAI JUMEIRAH RESORT","image":"","stars":"","highlights":""}}
]
}
```

Edit: Someone mentioned that I should not loop over data rather than data.promos I tried this but it doesn't help. I am new to JSON:

```
for (var i=0, len=data.promos.length; i < len; i++) 
     {
        alert(data.promos[i]);
    }
```

Comment: You're treating the json data as an array even though the top level is an object. You should be using data.promos where you're using data.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is the result of the asker not appropriately handling the structure of their specific data, not something more generally relevant, and does not include error messages or other descriptions of what actually happens instead of the intended result. 

Comment: There is no error. Nothing happens and no alert box appears

Comment: Could you post your list.php file code to question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$.each(data.promo, function(key, value) {
        console.log(value.id);
        //and so on...
});
```

Comment: _foreach_ is soooooo much easier than a traditionnal _for(blabla)_

Comment: Ok it now loops all right but displays undefined when I try to get any value (id for example as you posted)

Answer (score 4):

`data` is an object, with one property (`promos`), not an array. You can't loop over it. (You can loop over `data.promos`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Loop is working now but when I try to get the value of id as value.id (using each loop now and each promo is a value) I get undefined can you please tell what might be the problem @quentin

Comment: @AhmarAli: Are you using `data[i].id`? It’s `data[i].promo.id`.

Comment: @minitech I am using this $.each(data.promos, function(key, value) {
        console.log(value.id);
        
});

Comment: @AhmarAli: `console.log(value.promo.id);`

Answer (score 1):

Note, that the top-level property of your JSON-Data is named `promos`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript"
            type="text/javascript"
            src="./jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function getList() {

        $.getJSON( "http://localhost:8888/testbed/jsonProvider.php", function( data ){

            // Use JavaScript's log facility to learn what's inside a variable
            console.log( data );

            var len = data.promos.length;

            for ( var i=0; i < len; i++ ) {

                alert( data.promos[i].promo.id );

            }

        });

    }

    getList();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and this PHP data provider `jsonProvider.php`:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
?>
{
"promos":[
{"promo":{"id":"1","name":"MADINAT JUMEIRAH AL QASR","image":"","stars":"","highlights":""}},
{"promo":{"id":"2","name":"MADINAT JUMEIRAH DAR AL MASYAF","image":"","stars":"","highlights":""}},
{"promo":{"id":"3","name":"ATLANTIS THE PALM","image":"","stars":"","highlights":""}},
{"promo":{"id":"4","name":"JUMEIRAH ZABEEL SARAY 5*","image":"","stars":"","highlights":""}},
{"promo":{"id":"5","name":"HABTOOR GRAND BEACH RESORT & SPA","image":"","stars":"","highlights":""}},
{"promo":{"id":"6","name":"HILTON DUBAI JUMEIRAH RESORT","image":"","stars":"","highlights":""}}
]
}
```